# HttpClient timeouts without reason

Tags: c#, dns, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

In my .net Application I am using the Microsoft's HttpClient to send Requests to a server. In my team we have a problem that several people get a timeout on each single request without any knowledgable reason.

Following code is used to send the request:

```
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
// Here are some values that are identical on each system.
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://myservice.com/endpoint", content);
```

Is there any known issue or reason that the httpClient runs into a timeout on specific systems?

Important fact: Calling the same endpoint with the same data via Postman works on every collegues system.

EDIT:

The error message is:

> "The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of
> 100 seconds elapsing."

When navigating through the inner Exceptions the native error code is 995 and SocketErrorCode is OperationAborted

What I expect:

After max. 5 Secs there should a 200 Response with Json Data.

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"? Are you getting an exception? Is there an error message? What result do you expect? We need more information.

Comment: Edited my question with some more information.

@Fildor what does that mean? Wouldn't that mean that my Service has some restrictions set?

Comment: Port exhaustion would not cause a timeout. It would cause a different kind of error before the request is sent.

Comment: [`995` is `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`](https://errorcodelookup.com/?type=win32&code=000003E3)

Comment: Right. Then maybe OP should track what's going on the line from / to PostMan vs C# and look at the diff ...

Comment: Did you try calling it using PostMan on that system too? Did you check the connection quality and the proxy configuration on that system ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was that c# couldn't resolve the DNS name on particular systems and Postman could...

Comment: No, that's not it. DNS resolution is performed by the OS, not Postman or C#. You had a DNS problem, but still don't know why. *Maybe* what you posted isn't the real code, and `_httpClient` is a field holding a long-lived HttpClient instance. Maybe, the DNS entry changed so the IP addresses and sockets used by HttpClient are now invalid. That's why you should use HttpClientFactory instead of a static/long-lived HttpClient

Comment: The reason HttpClient is fast is that it performs DNS resolution just once, then caches the network socket created for the first call. DNS resolution is *slooow* and can take up to 15 seconds. Caching the socket leads to huge performance benefits. If the DNS entry changes though, something *very* common in load-balanced web apps or in case of fail-over, the socket will point to the wrong IP. HttpClientFactory creates HttpClient instances that use a pool of sockets managed and more importantly *recycled* by HttpClientFactory. This way, if DNS changes the new IP will be picked up in10 minutes